WP-Members でログイン済みのユーザーがログインページにアクセスした時にホームヘ飛ぶようにしたい
ログインした時にリダイレクト設定は以下のコードでOKですが、
// ログイン時にリダイレクト
add_filter( 'wpmem_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 2 );
 function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $user_id ) {
     return 'https://www.XXXXXX.XXX/'; /* ←転送させたい宛先を指定 */
 }

通常のログインページ上では、「クリックしてサインアウト」と表示されますが、そのサインアウト表示ではなく、ホームへ飛ぶようにすることは可能なんでしょうか。
＊ログイン済みのユーザーが 'https://www.XXXXXX.XXX/login' にクリックした時、
通常のログインページには、「クリックしてサインアウト」と表示されますが、その表示ではなく、ホーム（サイトトップ）へ飛ぶようにしたいとのことですが、あちこち情報をネットで検索しても参考になる情報がありませんでした。
　
代わりにChat GPTで問い合わせしてみました結果、以下のコードで試しましたが効きませんでした。　
どこか記述する実装方法が間違っているのではないかと思いますが、そのコードがおかしいとかヒントありましたらご指摘いただけると幸いです。　また、参考になる情報があればご教授いただけると助かります。　まだまだ初心者で申し訳ないですが、勉強します！　
よろしくお願いいたします。
    // ログイン済みのユーザーを検出し、ログインページにアクセスした場合はホームページにリダイレクト
function redirect_wpmem_logged_in_users() {
    // ログイン済みの場合
    if ( is_user_wpmem_logged_in() && is_page('login') ) {
        // ホームページのURLを取得
        $home_url = home_url('/');
        // ホームページにリダイレクト
        wp_redirect($home_url);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_wpmem_logged_in_users');

